# Preserve 3d not working on ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms, preserve-3d

I'm trying to implement a flip on an image but its preserve 3d (or probably backface-visibility) is not working on ie11.

**This solution didn't work for me:** [-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664255/webkit-transform-style-preserve-3d-not-working)

Here is a pen for you to try stuff and also a fiddle: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/XbedKY?editors=110

```css
.container {
  -ms-perspective: 1500px;
  perspective: 1500px;
}
.canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow: visible;
}
.canvas img {
  max-width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
input:checked + .canvas {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.red {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="canvas">
    <img src="http://todofondosdeamor.com/wp-content/uploads/images/48/gatitos-1__400x300.jpg">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>That checkbox over there</p>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support it http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer doesn't support preserve-3d in any version (probably Spartan will).

You need to change the way you have set the transforms if you want it to work (on the item directly instead of the container)

```css
.container{
  perspective: 1500px;
}
.canvas{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow: visible;
}
.canvas img{
  max-width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
    transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
}
input:checked + .canvas img {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.red{
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform:  rotateY(180deg);
    transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
}
input:checked + .canvas .red {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="canvas">
    <img src="http://todofondosdeamor.com/wp-content/uploads/images/48/gatitos-1__400x300.jpg">
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>That checkbox over there</p>
```