# Transform in IE not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I edited a jsfiddle where you can flip a card.

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but when you open it in IE it doesn't work properly...

```
.flip .card.flipped {
 -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
```

The back of the card isn't shown in IE... What am I doing wrong?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MichaHumbel/asd17pb2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve 3d not working on ie11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919489/preserve-3d-not-working-on-ie11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

> Partial support in IE refers to not supporting the transform-style: preserve-3d property. This prevents nesting 3D transformed elements.

Since you are using transform-style: preserve-3d property in your code, this is the issue.

EDIT:
[Preserve 3d not working on ie11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919489/preserve-3d-not-working-on-ie11) similar problem, and they found solution. Hope it helps, you too.