# In Safari the center of the 3D Carousel is not right, Edge, Chrome is working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, 3d, carousel

I'm using the Guid here: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-3d-rotating-carousel-css-javascript/, it works fine but not in safari. I try to find out what Safari does different to other Browser in this case. I guess a certain Math function like: theta =  2 * Math.PI / numImages,in Safari creates another reference to find a center in 3D space, z axis.

I can't really dig much deeper myself. I should try to move the object bit more far from Screen on z axis

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head
 <body>
<div class="carousel">
    <figure>
   <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/7mUXaBBrhoA/800x533" alt="" name="bar">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/bjhrzvzZeq4/800x533" alt="" name="bar1">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/EbuaKnSm8Zw/800x533" alt="" name="bar2">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/kG38b7CFzTY/800x533" alt="" name="bar3">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/nvzvOPQW0gc/800x533" alt="" name="bar4">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/mCg0ZgD7BgU/800x533" alt="" name="bar5">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1FWICvPQdkY/800x533" alt="" name="bar6">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/VkwRmha1_tI/800x533" alt="" name="bar7">
    </figure>
    <nav>
        <button class="nav prev">Prev</button>
        <button class="nav next">Next</button>
    </nav>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="bar" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Options</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal content..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="bar1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 1 Options</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal 1 content..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="bar2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Options</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal content..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="bar3" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal 3</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal 3 content..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
//  $(this).css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"})
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
 // console.log(name);
  $('#' + name).modal({show: true});
});


var
    carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel'),
    figure = carousel.querySelector('figure'),
    nav = carousel.querySelector('nav'),
    numImages = figure.childElementCount,
    theta =  2 * Math.PI / numImages,
    currImage = 0
;

nav.addEventListener('click', onClick, true);

function onClick(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var t = e.target;
    if (t.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BUTTON')
        return;

    if (t.classList.contains('next')) {
        currImage++;
    }
    else {
        currImage--;
    }

    figure.style.transform = `rotateY(${currImage * -theta}rad)`;
}
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.plakat {
  width: 100%

}

.carousel {
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
          perspective: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.carousel > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.carousel figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -482.8427124746px;
          transform-origin: 50% 50% -482.8427124746px;
}
.carousel figure img {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 40px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.carousel figure img:not(:first-of-type) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -482.8427124746px;
          transform-origin: 50% 50% -482.8427124746px;
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0.7853981634rad);
          transform: rotateY(0.7853981634rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(1.5707963268rad);
          transform: rotateY(1.5707963268rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(2.3561944902rad);
          transform: rotateY(2.3561944902rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(3.1415926536rad);
          transform: rotateY(3.1415926536rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(3.926990817rad);
          transform: rotateY(3.926990817rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(4.7123889804rad);
          transform: rotateY(4.7123889804rad);
}
.carousel figure img:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(5.4977871438rad);
          transform: rotateY(5.4977871438rad);
}
.carousel nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.carousel nav button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/scribbi/pen/ZPRzrp

it should look like this: [image: 3d Carousel]

But it looks like that: [image: wrong rendering 3D carousel]

As we can see here: http://thenewcode.com/736/Advanced-CSS-3D-Carousel the problem already exists, Safari "displaces the transform-origin-z coordinate for the gallery, pushing it forward in the browser"

for some reason it is rotating around the center of the fifth Image, while the first image is positioned deeper in the carousel.
Another approach here: https://codepen.io/scribbi/pen/BEjJLY is functioning in these Browsers, no SCSS is used and more hardcoding needed. As well it's not yet responsive.
maybe related: [-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664255/webkit-transform-style-preserve-3d-not-working)

Comment: Safari ? which one, which version, which system ?

Comment: MacBook Pro Version 12.0.3 (14606.4.5)

Comment: iPhone iOS 12.2

Comment: try with sass ?

Comment: Safari 3 don't do 3D Transforms

Comment: Chrom Mobile as well not showing the correct Carousel. v. 73.0.3683.68 on iPhone 8 iOS 12.2

Comment: use html5test.com on each of them, and you'll see which css commands work or not